# How to easily find files with no extension using Windows

Tags: windows-explorer, powershell, cmd.exe, search, file-extension

I have some files on my Hard Disk Drive that have no extensions whatsoever. It is very hard to find them manually, I really don't like the fact that I would need to replace my mouse sooner because of the not vast, but yet very prominent damage, done to the hardware from trying to find those files by constantly clicking and scrolling, since they are a few hundred files out of thousands in a single folder.

Does anyone here know of a `cmd` or `PowerShell` command, or some Windows Explorer search advanced query syntax to help simplify this task?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: are you joking with that Lorem Ipsum text?

Comment: Explorer: `kind:= -folder extension:= ""`.

Comment: @PetSerAl doesn't seem to be working unfortunately(also tried tweaking it, swapping them around but nothing).

Comment: @computationalprince It seems to work only in indexed locations. This should work in not indexed locations too: `kind:= -folder type:= -[] extension:= []`.

Comment: To take that even a step further (just a tad) you can use `kind:= -folder type:= -[] extension:= [] folder:"C:\folder\path"` essentially putting the `folder:"C:\folder\path"` into the mix with the **File Explorer Advanced Query Syntax** to not search recursive and only for the specific folder enclosed in the double quotes. Very nice @PetSerAl!!!

Comment: @PetSerAl See my updated answer with this helpful tip you provided I thought is too good to just be a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted, seems a perfect question to me. +1

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers It was probably downvoted during the initial... revision/edit war. The question wasn't always this (intel)legible.

Comment: Fair enough, but people should reverse their downvotes when a question is fixed/edited. I'd love to know how he ended up with a bunch of files without extensions...  But thats irrelevant really

Comment: @PetSerAl: I find that `kind:-folder extension:[]` and `type:-folder extension:[]` seem to be good enough (on Windows 7).  Why do you put `=` and space between the property name (keyword) and the restriction (value)?

Comment: @Scott Space is the matter of style, I just think, it look better this way. `=` is likely not necessary in this case, but I like to be explicit: some properties use partial match by default, and it is how autocompletion do it too. And without `type:= -[]` it does find not filesystem items like internet history items, depending of your search location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Finding Files with No File Extensions with Windows

### [Windows Explorer - Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266512(v=vs.85).aspx)

*As per [**PetSerAl**](https://superuser.com/users/364455) here are some of the **File Explorer Advanced Query Syntax** method to start with but read further down for the equivalent **Command Line** and **Batch Script** methods for this task.*

**Recursive Search**

```
kind:= -folder type:= -[] extension:= []
```

**Non-Recursive**

Just select the "**Current Folder**" option thru the GUI "**Search**" tab

[image]

or

```
kind:= -folder type:= -[] extension:= [] folder:"C:\folder\path"
```

---

You can use a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop iterating the output of a [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command with the `/B` and `/A-D` parameters, and then use some  conditional [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic to only output files without any extensions using substitutions for the iterated files in the specified directory.

### Command Line

**Note:** *This assumes the directory you are in on the command line is the directory you are needing to search to display the files without extensions.*

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A IN ('dir /B * /A-D') DO IF /I [%~nxA]==[%~nA] ECHO %~A
```

---

### Batch Script

**Note:** *This is a batch script that you set the `SET Src=` value to be the directory which you need to search to display files without extensions.*

```
@ECHO ON
SET Src=C:\folder\path
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /B "%Src%\*" /A-D') DO IF /I [%%~nxA]==[%%~nA] ECHO %%~A
PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- `FOR /?`

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > ```
- [Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: From CMDs point of view, every file name containing a dot has an extension even if it's not one. So it might be worth checking the extension for validity by length or content. (assoc will list known extensions)

Comment: It is quite easy to switch between recursive/non-recursive search thru [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S57D1.png).

Comment: (1) The question does not specify a Windows version. Windows 7 and earlier do not have File Explorer; Windows Explorer (as explicitly cited by the OP) does not have a ribbon or anything similar to the “Search” tab you show. (2) FYI, I can confirm that the `kind:= -folder type:= -[] extension:= []` Advanced Query Syntax works in Windows 7. But so does `kind:-folder type:-[] extension:[]` — you don’t need the `=` signs (or the spaces after them). In fact, `kind:-folder extension:[]` and `type:-folder extension:[]` seem to be good enough. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) When does ```dir /B * /A-D``` produce a different result than `dir /B /A-D` (i.e., when does `dir *` produce a different result than `dir`)?

Answer (score 3):

For the PowerShell solution:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File -Filter '*.'
```

Or:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File | Where-Object Extension -eq ''
```

Note that the `-File` parameter requires PowerShell v3+.

Answer (score 1):

In Command Prompt, just use `*.`:

```
C:\directory\name> dir

08/24/2018  03:33 AM              .
08/24/2018  03:33 AM              ..
08/24/2018  03:33 AM                16 a
08/24/2018  03:33 AM                18 b.c
08/24/2018  03:33 AM                20 d.e.f
               3 File(s)             54 bytes

C:\directory\name> dir *.

08/24/2018  03:33 AM              .
08/24/2018  03:33 AM              ..
08/24/2018  03:33 AM                16 a
               1 File(s)             16 bytes

C:\directory\name>
```

Remember, the Windows Command Prompt is not Unix. 
In Unix filenames, dot (**`.`**) is just an ordinary character
(except for the fact that filename that begin with dot are hidden). 
In Unix, `*e*` means all filenames that contain an `e`,
and `*.*` means all filenames that *(explicitly)* contain a **`.`**.

The rules for Command Prompt are trickier. 
`*` means all filenames (even ones with an extension). 
And `*.*` also means all filenames (even ones that do not contain a **`.`**). 
But `*.` means all filenames that do not have an extension.

Comment: This also always matches the current and parent directory links of every directory you search in and that's not what you want when you search for files without an extension.

Comment: Windows Search is disabled at my PC. But the `*.` search worked flawlessly with the search tool "Everything" from voidtools.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | ? {$_.Extension -eq ''}
```

This uses maximum shorthand. But it's the same code as @BaconBits really.
I prefer shorthand. Its harder to read for beginner but more expressive and succinct

Comment: The reason why we have a minimum answer length is that we expect every post to have *some* level of explanation and / or commentary.